# ChartJS with ChartJS DataLabels: Change Color per Dataset for Value Labels

Tags: chart.js

I'm using ChartJS with the plug-in [ChartJS DataLabels](https://github.com/chartjs/chartjs-plugin-datalabels) to show text values right next to the points (who would have thought that a plugin is necessary for this basic task, but I digress).

My issue I need to v**ary the color of my text labels along with the individual dataset**. But so far I haven't found a solution. I'm adding new datasets **dynamically**, they're not statically pre-loaded. The color should match the color of the dataset.

Suppose I have

```
var colorpalette = ["red", "blue", "green", "magenta", "yellow", "brown", "purple", "orange", "black", "gray"];
var currseriesnum = 0;
var chart = null;

function setUpChart() {

    var ctx = document.getElementById('chartArea').getContext('2d');
    chart = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'line',
        data: {
            labels: monthnames, 
            datasets: [] // Initially blank - series added dynamically with chart.update()
        }, 
        options: {
            legend: {
                display: false
            },          
            scales: {
                yAxes: [{
                    ticks: {
                        beginAtZero: true
                    }
                }]
            }, 
            plugins: {  // ChartsJS DataLabels initialized here
                datalabels: {
                    anchor: 'end',
                    align: 'bottom',
                    formatter: Math.round,
                    font: {
                      weight: 'bold', 
                      size: 16
                    },
                    color: colorpalette[currseriesnum] // Pick color dynamically
                }
            }           
        }
    });     

}
```

Doesn't work. Also tried a function, `color: function(context)`, but unsure how to retrieve the current index of the dataset I'm getting here.

[image]

I'm adding series to the chart dynamically (initially empty) as below, and incrementing the global var `currseriesnum`.

```
chart.data.datasets.push({
    label: keyValueSelection.label, 
    fill: false, 
    data: keyValueSelection.value, 
    borderColor: colorpalette[currseriesnum], 
    borderWidth: 2
});
chart.update();
currseriesnum++;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They gave me the answer on the ChartJS DataLabels forum:

```
plugins: {
    datalabels: {
        color: function(ctx) {
            // use the same color as the border
            return ctx.dataset.borderColor
        }
    }
}
```